# How to draw this kind of block diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to draw block diagram as attached in the figure. I tried to draw and don't know how to add Arrows and label the bigbox I used. Can anyone help to draw such block diagram either completing from the existing code or by new way?[image]

I tried to draw by following code:

```
    \begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3.7cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=0.5em, text centered, minimum height=1em]
\tikzstyle{block1}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=2em, text centered,minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{block2}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=4em, text centered,minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{block3}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=8em, text centered,minimum height=5em]
\tikzstyle{bigbox} = [draw=black,thick, rectangle]
\tikzstyle{triple}=[draw, anchor=text, thick, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3]
\tikzstyle{double}=[draw, anchor=text, thick, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2]
%\tikzstyle{textbox} = {draw, fill=white, thick,text=black}
\node[block] (A) {};
\node[block] (B) [below=0.2cm of A] {}; 
\node[block] (C) [below=0.2cm of B] {}; 
\node[block] (D) [below=0.2cm of C] {}; 
\node[block] (E) [below=0.2cm of D] {}; 
\node[block] (F) [below=0.2cm of E] {}; 
\node[block] (G) [right=0.4cm of C] {};
\node[block] (H) [right=0.1cm of G] {};
\node[block] (I) [right=0.1cm of H] {};
\node[block] (J) [right=0.3cm of I] {};
\node[block] (K) [right=0.1cm of J] {};
\node[block] (L) [right=0.1cm of K] {};

\node[block] (P) [right=2cm of L] {};
\node[block] (Q) [right=0.1cm of P] {};
\node[block] (R) [right=0.1cm of Q] {};
\node[block] (S) [right=0.3cm of R] {};
\node[block] (T) [right=0.1cm of S] {};
\node[block] (U) [right=0.1cm of T] {};
\node[block] (X) [right=0.3cm of U] {};
\node[block] (Y) [above=0.2cm of X] {};
\node[block] (Z) [above=0.2cm of Y] {};
\node[block] (Aa) [below=0.2cm of X] {};
\node[block] (Ab) [below=0.2cm of Aa] {};
\node[block] (Ac) [below=0.2cm of Ab] {};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node[bigbox] (M) [fit = (G) (H) (I)] {};
     \node[bigbox] (N) [fit = (J) (K) (L)] {};
     \node[bigbox] (V) [fit = (P) (Q) (R)] {};
     \node[bigbox] (W) [fit = (S) (T) (U)] {};

    \node[bigbox] (O) [fit = (A) (B) (C) (D) (E) (F) (G) (H) (I) (J) (K) (L) (N)] {};
    \node[bigbox] (Ad) [fit = (P) (Q) (R) (S) (T) (U) (V) (W) (Aa) (Ac) (Z)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Proposed Framework} \label{fig1}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: You should read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles

Answer (score 5):

Although `jakun` already provided a solution, this is an alternative one.

`Source` and `Destination` can be added as labels of largest `fit` nodes:

```
  \node[bigbox, label=source] (O) [fit = (A) (F) (N)] {};
```

(I've simplified `fit` parameter to only include significant nodes and not all of them)

And as an alternative to `jakun's` `transform canvas` (which I didn't know) you could use:

```
\draw[<-] ([yshift=8mm]O.south east) coordinate (aux) -- node[below] {Ack} (aux-|Ad.west);
```

or with `calc` tikzlibrary:

```
\draw[->] ($(O.north east)!.2!(O.south east)$) -- ($(Ad.north west)!.2!(Ad.south west)$);
```

The complete code could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, backgrounds, fit}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3.7cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45, font=\sffamily]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=0.5em, text centered, minimum height=1em]
\tikzstyle{block1}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=2em, text centered,minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{block2}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=4em, text centered,minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{block3}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=8em, text centered,minimum height=5em]
\tikzstyle{bigbox} = [draw=black,thick, rectangle]
\tikzstyle{triple}=[draw, anchor=text, thick, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3]
\tikzstyle{double}=[draw, anchor=text, thick, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2]
%\tikzstyle{textbox} = {draw, fill=white, thick,text=black}
\node[block] (A) {};
\node[block] (B) [below=0.2cm of A] {}; 
\node[block] (C) [below=0.2cm of B] {}; 
\node[block] (D) [below=0.2cm of C] {}; 
\node[block] (E) [below=0.2cm of D] {}; 
\node[block] (F) [below=0.2cm of E] {}; 
\node[block] (G) [right=0.4cm of C] {};
\node[block] (H) [right=0.1cm of G] {};
\node[block] (I) [right=0.1cm of H] {};
\node[block] (J) [right=0.3cm of I] {};
\node[block] (K) [right=0.1cm of J] {};
\node[block] (L) [right=0.1cm of K] {};

\node[block] (P) [right=2cm of L] {};
\node[block] (Q) [right=0.1cm of P] {};
\node[block] (R) [right=0.1cm of Q] {};
\node[block] (S) [right=0.3cm of R] {};
\node[block] (T) [right=0.1cm of S] {};
\node[block] (U) [right=0.1cm of T] {};
\node[block] (X) [right=0.3cm of U] {};
\node[block] (Y) [above=0.2cm of X] {};
\node[block] (Z) [above=0.2cm of Y] {};
\node[block] (Aa) [below=0.2cm of X] {};
\node[block] (Ab) [below=0.2cm of Aa] {};
\node[block] (Ac) [below=0.2cm of Ab] {};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node[bigbox] (M) [fit = (G) (H) (I)] {};     
  \node[bigbox] (N) [fit = (J) (K) (L)] {};
  \node[bigbox] (V) [fit = (P) (Q) (R)] {};
  \node[bigbox] (W) [fit = (S) (T) (U)] {};

  \node[bigbox, label=source] (O) [fit = (A) (F) (N)] {};
  \node[bigbox, label=destination] (Ad) [fit = (Z) (Ac) (V)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\path (M.south) -- node[below] {Packets} (N.south);
\path (V.south) -- node[below] {Packets} (W.south);

\draw[->] ([yshift=-8mm]O.north east) coordinate (aux) -- (aux-|Ad.west);
\draw[<-] ([yshift=8mm]O.south east) coordinate (aux) -- node[below] {Ack} (aux-|Ad.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Proposed Framework} \label{fig1}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** The code could be simplified with the help of some `matrix` nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, fit, matrix}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    shorten >=1pt,
    shorten <=1pt,
    >=stealth',
    font=\sffamily,
    block/.style = {rectangle, black, thick, text width=0.5em, text centered, minimum height=1em},
    packet/.style={draw, thick, matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={block, draw}},
    bigbox/.style={rectangle, draw, thick}
    ]

\matrix (A1) [packet, draw=none, row sep=2mm]{ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ };
\matrix (B1) [packet, column sep=2mm, right=3mm of A1]{ & & \\};
\matrix (C1) [packet, column sep=2mm, right=1mm of B1]{ & & \\};
\node[bigbox, label=Source] (D1) [fit = (A1) (C1)] {};

\matrix (C2) [packet, column sep=2mm, right=2cm of C1]{ & & \\};
\matrix (B2) [packet, column sep=2mm, right=1mm of C2]{ & & \\};
\matrix (A2) [packet, draw=none, row sep=2mm, right=3mm of B2]{ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ };
\node[bigbox, label=Destination] (D2) [fit = (A2) (C2)] {};

\path (B1.south) -- node[below] {Packets} (C1.south);
\path (B2.south) -- node[below] {Packets} (C2.south);

\draw[->, thick] ([yshift=-8mm]D1.north east) coordinate (aux) -- (aux-|D2.west);
\draw[<-, thick] ([yshift=8mm]D1.south east) coordinate (aux) -- node[below] {Ack} (aux-|D2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Proposed Framework} \label{fig1}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your code:

```
% arrows
\draw[->, transform canvas={yshift=-1cm}] (O.north east) -- (Ad.north west);
\draw[<-, transform canvas={yshift=1cm}] (O.south east) -- node[below]{ACK} (Ad.south west);
% invisible coordinates to position the labels
\node (channel-y-position) [below=0pt of O] {\strut};
\path (O) -- coordinate (channel-x-position) (Ad);
% labels
\node[above=0pt of O] {Source};
\node[above=0pt of Ad] {Destination};
\node at (channel-x-position |- channel-y-position) {Channel};
```

---

I would use loops:

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3.7cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=0.5em, text centered, minimum height=1em]
    \tikzstyle{block1}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=2em, text centered,minimum height=3em]
    \tikzstyle{block2}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=4em, text centered,minimum height=2em]
    \tikzstyle{block3}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=8em, text centered,minimum height=5em]
    \tikzstyle{bigbox} = [draw=black,thick, rectangle]
    \tikzstyle{triple}=[draw, anchor=text, thick, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3]
    \tikzstyle{double}=[draw, anchor=text, thick, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2]
    %\tikzstyle{textbox} = {draw, fill=white, thick,text=black}

    \newcommand{\numVer}{6}
    \newcommand{\numHor}{3}
    \newcommand{\numHorGroups}{2}

    % ------ source ------
    % vertical
    \node[block] (source-ver-1) {};
    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \last (initially 1)] in {2,...,\numVer} {
        \node[block] (source-ver-\i) [below=0.2cm of source-ver-\last] {}; 
    }

    % horizontal
    \coordinate[right=.1cm of source-ver-3] (source-hor-group-0);
    \foreach \group [remember=\group as \lastGroup (initially 0)] in {1,...,\numHorGroups} {
        \node[block] (source-hor-\group-1) [right=0.3cm of source-hor-group-\lastGroup] {};
        \foreach \i [remember=\i as \last (initially 1)] in {2,...,\numHor} {
            \node[block] (source-hor-\group-\i) [right=.1cm of source-hor-\group-\last] {}; 
        }
        \node[bigbox] (source-hor-group-\group) [fit = (source-hor-\group-1) (source-hor-\group-\numHor), label=below:Packet~\group] {};
    }

    % frame
    \node[bigbox, label=above:Source] (source) [fit = (source-ver-1) (source-ver-\numVer) (source-hor-group-\numHorGroups)] {};


    % ------ destination ------
    % horizontal
    \coordinate[right=2cm of source-hor-\numHorGroups-\numHor] (dest-hor-group-0);
    \foreach \group [remember=\group as \lastGroup (initially 0)] in {1,...,\numHorGroups} {
        \node[block] (dest-hor-\group-1) [right=0.3cm of dest-hor-group-\lastGroup] {};
        \foreach \i [remember=\i as \last (initially 1)] in {2,...,\numHor} {
            \node[block] (dest-hor-\group-\i) [right=.1cm of dest-hor-\group-\last] {}; 
        }
        \node[bigbox] (dest-hor-group-\group) [fit = (dest-hor-\group-1) (dest-hor-\group-\numHor), label=below:Packet~\group] {};
    }

    % vertical
    \coordinate[right=.3cm of dest-hor-group-\numHorGroups] (dest-ver-west);
    \node[block] (dest-ver-1) at (dest-ver-west |- source-ver-1) [anchor=west] {};
    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \last (initially 1)] in {2,...,\numVer} {
        \node[block] (dest-ver-\i) [below=0.2cm of dest-ver-\last] {}; 
    }

    % frame
    \node[bigbox, label=above:Destination] (dest) [fit = (dest-ver-1) (dest-ver-\numVer) (dest-hor-group-1)] {};

    % ------ arrows ------
    % arrows
    \draw[->, transform canvas={yshift=-1cm}] (source.north east) -- (dest.north west);
    \draw[<-, transform canvas={yshift=1cm}] (source.south east) -- node[below]{ACK} (dest.south west);
    % invisible coordinates to position the labels
    \node (channel-y-position) [below=0pt of source] {\strut};
    \coordinate (channel-x-position) at ($(source.east)!.5!(dest.west)$);
    % labels
    \node at (channel-x-position |- channel-y-position) {Channel};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I canged some parts of your code, e.g. to get more square nodes and to line up the output and input buffer in the center of the packets list. By uing `calc` library as well as `-|`, you can manipulate the coordinates to where yo want. I have not cared much about the fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,fit,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3.7cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45]
  % \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=0.5em, text centered, minimum height=1em]
  \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=black, thick, inner sep=0pt,minimum width=1em, minimum height=1em]
  % \tikzstyle{block1}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=2em, text centered,minimum height=3em]
  % \tikzstyle{block2}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=4em, text centered,minimum height=2em]
  % \tikzstyle{block3}=[rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=8em, text centered,minimum height=5em]
  \tikzstyle{bigbox} = [draw=black,thick, rectangle]
  % \tikzstyle{triple}=[draw, anchor=text, thick, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3]
  % \tikzstyle{double}=[draw, anchor=text, thick, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2]
  % \tikzstyle{textbox} = {draw, fill=white, thick,text=black}
  \node[block] (A) {};
  \node[block] (B) [below=0.2cm of A] {}; 
  \node[block] (C) [below=0.2cm of B] {}; 
  \node[block] (D) [below=0.2cm of C] {}; 
  \node[block] (E) [below=0.2cm of D] {}; 
  \node[block] (F) [below=0.2cm of E] {}; 
  \node[block] (G) [right=0.4cm of {$(C.south east)!0.5!(D.north east)$}] {};
  \node[block] (H) [right=0.1cm of G] {};
  \node[block] (I) [right=0.1cm of H] {};
  \node[block] (J) [right=0.3cm of I] {};
  \node[block] (K) [right=0.1cm of J] {};
  \node[block] (L) [right=0.1cm of K] {};

  \node[block] (P) [right=2cm of L] {};
  \node[block] (Q) [right=0.1cm of P] {};
  \node[block] (R) [right=0.1cm of Q] {};
  \node[block] (S) [right=0.3cm of R] {};
  \node[block] (T) [right=0.1cm of S] {};
  \node[block] (U) [right=0.1cm of T] {};
  \node[block] (X) [right=0.3cm of {U.east |- C}] {};
  \node[block] (Y) [above=0.2cm of X] {};
  \node[block] (Z) [above=0.2cm of Y] {};
  \node[block] (Aa) [below=0.2cm of X] {};
  \node[block] (Ab) [below=0.2cm of Aa] {};
  \node[block] (Ac) [below=0.2cm of Ab] {};

  % \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node[bigbox] (M) [fit = (G) (H) (I)] {};
  \node[bigbox] (N) [fit = (J) (K) (L)] {};
  \node[bigbox] (V) [fit = (P) (Q) (R)] {};
  \node[bigbox] (W) [fit = (S) (T) (U)] {};

  \node[bigbox,label=above:Source] (O) [fit = (A) (B) (C) (D) (E) (F) (G) (H) (I) (J) (K) (L) (N)] {};
  \node[bigbox,label=above:Destination] (Ad) [fit = (P) (Q) (R) (S) (T) (U) (V) (W) (Aa) (Ac) (Z)] {};
  % \end{pgfonlayer}
  \draw[->](O.30)--(Ad.180 |- O.30);
  \draw[<-](O.-30)--(Ad.180 |- O.-30)node[pos=0.5,below]{ACK};
  \node[below=1em] at ($(O.south east)!0.5!(Ad.south west)$){CHANNEL};
  \node[below] at ($(M.south)!0.5!(N.south)$){Packets};
  \node[below] at ($(V.south)!0.5!(W.south)$){Packets};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]